# MongoDB $IN query with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to fetch data from my MongoDB with PHP. In the DB I have a "readAccess" field that contains an array with IDs.
I tested the following statement SUCCESSFULLY in my MongoDB GUI client:

```
db.myDB.find({
  "location.parentLocationId": 808,
  "readAccess": {
    "$in": [12, 4]
  }
})
```

On PHP side I "translated" the query into (condition only):

```
array(
  'location.parentLocationId' => 808,
  'readAccess' => array(
      '$in' => array(12, 4)
  )
)
```

But with the php version of the query I don't get any results...
I can not see a difference between these queries. Can anyone give me some help?

Thank you!

Philip

Comment: if $in is a php variable, use double quotes!

Comment: That looks totally correct to me, in fact I have this exact code working in my own PHP applications. Are you sure the query is getting to the server? Take a look in the MongoDB logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... The array keys in the $in were not formatted as integer. Thats why **MongoDB** did not output anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I did not get it as I am facing the same issue please post a solution `$cursor = $collection->find( array("client_id" =>array("$in" => array("D0242"))))` is not working